# How to change the current scene to another in JavaFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

There is a main stage and a controller with him on stage one button, when clicked, I want to change the current scene to the next, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Main.java:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("first.fxml").openStream());
    FirstController firstController = loader.getController();
    firstController.setStage(primaryStage);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Stage");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

first.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.FirstController"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <Label text="first scene" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Button text="second" onAction="#second" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</GridPane>
```

FirstController.java:

```
private Stage mStage;

public void setStage(Stage mStage) {
    this.mStage = mStage;
}


public void second(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = (Parent)      loader.load(getClass().getResource("second.fxml").openStream());
    SecondController secondController = loader.getController();
    secondController.setStage(mStage);

    mStage.setTitle("second scene");
    mStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    mStage.show();
}
```

second.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.SecondController"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <Label text="second scene" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Button text="first" onAction="#first" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</GridPane>
```

SecondController.java

```
private Stage mStage;

public void setStage(Stage mStage) {
    this.mStage = mStage;
}


public void first(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("first.fxml").openStream());
    FirstController firstController = loader.getController();
    firstController.setStage(mStage);

    mStage.setTitle("first scene");
    mStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    mStage.show();
}
```

And second.fxml can be any fxml you like. It is realy simple, you just need to get controller from the loader and pass instance of your Application class to it.

Note that this is short verision of my code and I had to delete some stuff for the simplicity, so it might won't work if you just copy&paste. If I missed anything let me know.

Comment: Thank you! But i get mistakes, setStage is not called. Why?

Comment: I add the member public FirstController controller; in main class, and called controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setStage(stage); // << THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART

Comment: Ok I edited code. It should be working example now (copy&paste from IDE). I think it's not the best method how to do it but it depends on your application architecture. This is just basic idea how it can work. If you are satisfied, please accept it as answer and vote up :)